# Shared Variable in C# .Net MVC Thread

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, delegates, shared-memory

I am uploading videos to server in .Net MVC application. Since it is takes some time I am doing in a background thread. On the other hand I am tracking the upload progress and display it to the user.

Here is my code

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    long chunkSize = 256 * 1024;
    private static string _progress = ""; //if I make nonstatic it fails 

    //..........
    //Some codes here
    //..........

    //Upload file Request
    public ActionResult VideoUploader()
    {
        var client = (VimeoClient)Session["client"];
        Ticket t = client.vimeo_videos_upload_getTicket();

        string path = @"E:\d2.MOV"; //Hardcoded value for testing purposes

        new Thread(() => Transfer(client, t, path)).Start(); //Push file to server in background

        return PartialView("_progress", "Preparing to upload...");
    }

    //Worker Thread
    private void Transfer(VimeoClient client, Ticket t, string path)
    {
        FileInfo UploadFile = new FileInfo(path);

        int chunks = (int)Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(UploadFile.Length / chunkSize)); 

        for (int i = 0; i <= chunks; i++)
        {
            string output = client.PostVideo(t, i, path,(int) chunkSize);

            var v = client.vimeo_videos_upload_verifyChunks(t);

            double percentage = (Convert.ToDouble(i + 1) / (chunks + 1)) * 100;

            _progress = percentage.ToString() + "%"; // value sharing between two actions

        }

        string name = client.vimeo_videos_upload_complete(path, t);
        client.vimeo_videos_embed_setPreset(client.Token, "200772", name);
    }

    //This method is calling from front end using jQuery to display progress
    public ActionResult Progress()
    {
            //returning updated shared "_progress" varibal
        return Json(_progress, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
}
```

My problem is when I made "_progress" nonstatic variable(`private static _progress`) it is not working. Value is always empty.

What I trying to do is share `_progress` variable between main thread and new thread. But it is failing when it nonstatic.

Please help me to correct. If you have a better option please share

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should be returning some sort of "operation ID" to the client as part of the original response. The `Progress` method should then *take* this operation ID as a parameter. The upload service should then store its progress against that operation ID (e.g. in a database, to allow you to scale horizontally).

Basically, you should imagine the situation where there are multiple transfers involved - you need some way of getting the progress for the *right* transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Instance of `MyController` is created per request.

After you spin the worker thread you return the page to the client and that instance is gone.

You can pass `this`(i.e. the controller instance) to the `Transfer` method like this

`new Thread(() => Transfer(this, client, t, path)).Start();`

and then access the _progress variable in the `Transfer` method like this

```
private void Transfer(MyController controller,
                                       VimeoClient client, Ticket t, string path)
{
    controller._progress
```

the page is already returned, so you'll just be able to access the instance _progress field, but then how do you update the client?

you can either

- return in the view an animated gif and make a periodical request to the server with javascript OR
- use a library like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to 'push' the progress update to the client

Comment: After 'VideoUploader' request came I push file in background using using private 'Transfer' method and returns a PartialView. Within the 'Transer' function I am updating '_progress' value. Returned PartaiView periodically calls to 'Progress' action to get the current progress values which is updated inside the 'Transfer' method. Since '_progress' is a static it is working. But two users upload files simultaneously '_progress' value gone crazy which is obvious b'cos it is shared. So I want to make '_progress' to nonstatic. But in that case value is always empty. Sharing doesn't work

Comment: sharing would work if you pass the instance of MyController(this) to your thread function as I suggest, there is one instance per request

Comment: thanx Bond. But the problem is how can I access that myContoller insatnce inside the 'Progress' Action. 

`public ActionResult Progress()
    {
            //returning updated shared "_progress" varibal
        return Json(_progress, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }`

Comment: well you can't from there, you'll have to do what Jon suggests - store the information of your uploads per client and make the Progress action take a key pointing into that store, you give the client the key with the view of your VideoUploader action.